# How To Properly Create a Histogram: Displaying the Frequency of the Tweets for Each Day Spanning 2 Years

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, twitter

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced at all with matplotlib (and similar libraries), and I find some of the avaiable tutorials confusing.

This is my problem:

I have list of timestamps in string format, like this:

```
timestamp_list = ['2017-01-30 23:45', '2017-01-30 20:30', '2017-01-30 18:22', '2017-01-29 17:39', '2017-01-29 15:39', '2017-01-29 14:45', '2017-01-29 11:51', '2017-01-29 11:15', '2017-01-29 09:41', '2017-01-30 05:54', '2017-01-29 03:10']
```

Each timestamp represents a tweet. I would like to build a histogram similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nVps.png), but **grouping my tweets per day**. So, ultimately, I would like this histogram to show how many tweets are being tweeted on a daily basis from my list.

I have no idea how to group these tweets day by day (or any other grouping, i.e. monthly). I don't know which is the most easy and painless way to do it, and most importantly, when I'm reading posts on how to use matplotlib to create histograms (and similar things, like CDFs), I don't understand what each line *specifically* does, and thus, I cannot edit these posts according to my needs and expand my knowledge.

Can someone please provide a sample solution of to create such a histogram using matplotlib (or similar), but also comment each line so that I can fully understand how to produce similar plots in the future?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:** I think that my original question wasn't clear enough, since none of the solutions suggested solve my problem. I'm sorry for not being more explicit. I will try to elaborate:

Let's say that I have a set of tweets of a specific topic spanning a duration of two years. This sums up to 730 days. `timestamp_list` is a list containing the unique timestamps of each tweet, in `string` format.

Every day in the duration of these two years is a **unique** day. That means that I have 730 unique days. What I want is to find out how many tweets of that specific topic were tweeted on every day of the 730 days. For instance, on `2017-01-20` there might have been 10 tweets, on `2017-01-21` 45 tweets, and so on. I would like to create a histogram based on this. Some people suggested creating a dictionary.

- How can I create a dictionary containing 730 keys and their respective number of tweets?
- How can I plot a histogram based on the previous dictionary?

Or, if there is another, more efficient way to do (instead of using dictionaries), it's also welcome.

What I want is to somehow take this `string` list and create a histogram, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nVps.png), showing the number of tweets tweeted on a daily basis, spanning the duration of the dates (in my case, 2 years).

---

**Bounty**:

Thank you all for your submissions. Both @cphlewis' and @TobiasRibizel' answers are correct. However, I'm inclined to pick @TobiasRibizel' answer as the winning answer, since it doesn't use third party libraries, it is very well explained, and it produces a very nice histogram, just like the one I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to parse the strings into `date` objects and create a histogram using pyplot's `hist` from this data:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# these lines are just there to create some data
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_list = [datetime(2017,randint(4,6),randint(1,30),randint(0,23),randint(0,59)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h:%m") for i in range(1000)]

# here the real code starts
dates = []
for t in timestamp_list:
    # extract the date part of the timestamp
    date_str = t.split(' ')[0]
    # extract the numbers from the date
    year,month,day = [int(i) for i in date_str.split('-')]
    # create a date object
    d = date(year, month, day)
    # and store it
    dates.append(d)

# sort the dates
dates.sort()

# extract the first and last date
min_date = dates[0]
max_date = dates[-1]

# compute the number of days
length = (max_date - min_date).days + 1

# show the histogram
plt.hist(dates, bins=length)
plt.show()
```

If you want a little bit more control over how your plot looks, I would recommend that you create the buckets for your histogram yourself and plot them using a `bar` plot:

```py
# initialize one empty bucket per day
buckets = [0 for i in range(length)]
days = [(min_date + timedelta(i)).isoformat() for i in range(length)]

for d in dates:
    days_from_begin = (d - min_date).days
    buckets[days_from_begin] += 1

# print a bar plot of the results
plt.bar(range(length), buckets)
# add x-axis ticks (dates)
plt.xticks(range(length), days, rotation=70)

# some cosmetics: hide all ticks
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
# show every 4th tick again
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels()[::4],visible=True)

# show the result
plt.show()
```

The output might look something like this:

[image: histogram of timestamp occurrence]

Answer (score 2):

New solution, having taken Tobias' comment in -- and once the timestamps are broken into the segments of interest, the histogram is built into `pandas` and is "date smart", that is, it will leave x-axis space for dates without tweets:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timestamp_list = ['2017-01-15 23:45', '2017-01-16 20:30', '2017-01-30 18:22',
                  '2017-01-29 17:39', '2017-01-29 15:39', '2017-01-29 14:45',
                  '2017-01-29 11:51', '2017-01-29 11:15', '2017-01-29 09:41',
                  '2017-01-30 05:54', '2017-01-29 03:10','2016-05-02 00:00',
                  '2016-05-23 00:00', '2016-03-29 00:00']

Tweetframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(timestamp_list), columns=['Tweets'])
Tweetframe['Date'] = map(lambda x: x.date(), Tweetframe.Tweets)

# Tweetframe.Date is a Series, which has a histogram method.
# By default it uses 10 bins; this sets the bins to number of days
# Nb: which is not exactly the same as grouping by Date. 
ax = Tweetframe.Date.hist(xrot=45,
                          bins = (Tweetframe.Date.max() -
                                      Tweetframe.Date.min()).days)

ax.set_ylabel('Tweet count')
ax.grid('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Leaving in: the first thing I thought of, which is precise in the x-axis values but you would have to fuss with to get the x-axis spacing to handle tweetless dates:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
timestamp_list = ['2017-01-30 23:45', '2017-01-30 20:30', '2017-01-30 18:22', '2017-01-29 17:39', '2017-01-29 15:39', '2017-01-29 14:45', '2017-01-29 11:51', '2017-01-29 11:15', '2017-01-29 09:41', '2017-01-30 05:54', '2017-01-29 03:10','2016-01-30 00:00','2016-01-29 00:00', '2017-03-29 00:00']



# Pandas works on DataFrames, so make a DataFrame. Make real datetimes because Pandas is also smart about datetimes: 
Tweetframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(timestamp_list), columns=['Tweets'])
# The groupby function groups the data by the cases given in the first argument; the result is a DataFrameGroupBy object, sort of a tiny database, which can count the elements in each group and then barplot the counts:
Tweetframe.groupby((Tweetframe['Tweets'].dt.year, Tweetframe['Tweets'].dt.month, Tweetframe['Tweets'].dt.day)).count().plot(kind="bar")
# I always need to do something to date-stamp xlabels to make them readable
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can your solution be modified to also include days where no tweets were posted? This way, the x-axis would be more continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You could use default dict and group them by date like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict


groups = defaultdict(list)
timestamp_list = ['2017-01-30 23:45', '2017-01-30 20:30', '2017-01-30 18:22', '2017-01-29 17:39', '2017-01-29 15:39', '2017-01-29 14:45', '2017-01-29 11:51', '2017-01-29 11:15', '2017-01-29 09:41', '2017-01-30 05:54', '2017-01-29 03:10']

for obj in timestamp_list:
    groups[obj[8:-6]].append(obj)

new_list = list(groups.values())

print(new_list)


[
 ['2017-01-30 23:45', '2017-01-30 20:30', '2017-01-30 18:22', '2017-01-30 05:54'],
 ['2017-01-29 17:39', '2017-01-29 15:39', '2017-01-29 14:45', '2017-01-29 11:51', '2017-01-29 11:15', '2017-01-29 09:41', '2017-01-29 03:10']
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this isn't what I'm looking for. Probably my mistake, I wasn't very clear. Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a dict to store the date and count of tweets. The first 2 lines after the for loop are just extracting the day from the timestamp, I split the timestamp on the whitespace and take the first part to get the date then i just extract the last 2 things from that which is the date.

```
date_dict = {}
for dayin timestamp_list:
  day = day.split(' ')[0]
  day = day[len(day)-2:len(day)]
  if day in date_dict.keys():
    date_dict[day] += 1
  else
    date_dict[day] = 1
```

now, you can get fancier by storing the month along with the date in the `dict` as they key as well.

Comment: Not a bad option at all! Nice one, plus one :), if you want, check my answer to see another cool alternative :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this isn't what I was looking for. But it's probably my mistake, I wasn't clear enough. Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Histograms are quite easy to do in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# generate data in list form here
plt.hist(list)
plt.show()
```

You can set number of bins by doing plt.hist(list, bins=*desired number*)

I'm not sure how matplotlib will handle the date strings, but what you could do is set a start date to be 0 and every other date is x (days after day 0). Then you can adjust number of bins so that 1 bin corresponds to one day.